# micron sanding apparatus

Tags: precession

I am in need to shave a special material (composite much like fiberglass/kevlar) from 30 microns down to 10 microns, on a consistent basis.

How would I make something like this? or is there anything out there that already does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's called a microtome. you can also use a diamond grit polishing system to thin down a microtome slice to sub-micron thickness, a technique common in preparing samples for transmission electron microscopy.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to go do some research on this now.

Comment: it looks like a microtome is used for cutting thin pieces off, can it also be used to sand down a larger object from 30-10 microns(say a 2"x10"x30microns)? to me it seems it could only cut a very small piece off the longer axes

Comment: @scott, you use a diamond grit polishing system to thin it to the desired dimensions.

Comment: Could you give me an example link to a device that does this?  The microtomes I find are no where close to what I think I need..

Comment: @scott, first look up ULTRAMICROTOME as a subject under "TEM sample preparation", I'll look some more here in a minute.

Comment: @scott, see Document: TEM Sample Preparation Tips | Thermo Fisher Scientific
https://www.fei.com/documents/tem-sample-preparation-tips/
TEM Sample Preparation Tips. When preparing samples for the transmission electron microscope (TEM), obtaining samples of uniform thinness (from 10-200 nm) is critical. There are a few different sample geometries, the most common of which is thin foils, or lamellae. A broad literature exists on the exact methods and ..